# Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, mime-message

Hello i keep getting this error after following a tutorial when trying to send SMTP emails using spring boot. `Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address`

#### `application.properties`:

```
#email configuration
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.password = ************
spring.mail.username = ******@gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

#### implementation file:

```
@Service("mailServiceImpl")
public class MailServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void send(String to, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException {

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(to);
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(body, true);

        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

And finally in the controller class called `HomeController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping (value="guest/reservation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Reservation createReservation(@RequestBody Reservation reservation) throws MessagingException {
        Reservation reservation1 =reservationservice.create(reservation);
        billingservice.create(reservation1);
        String body = "Welcome";
        //mailServiceImpl.send(reservation1.getGuest().getEmail(), "", body);
        System.out.println(reservation1.getGuest().getEmail());
        sendMail(reservation1.getGuest().getEmail(), "Reservation", body);
        return reservation1;
    }

    private void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException {
        mailServiceImpl.send(to, subject,  body);
    }
```

#### Error from console:

```
2016-01-09 16:22:28.989 ERROR 17396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address] with root cause

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:459)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at edu.sjsu.cmpe275Project.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:29)
    at edu.sjsu.cmpe275Project.controller.HomeController.sendMail(HomeController.java:69)
    at edu.sjsu.cmpe275Project.controller.HomeController.createReservation(HomeController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:299)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please what did i do wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the email address of the sender?

Comment: @RomanC yes from the controller i retrieved the email reservation1.getGuest().getEmail() and also specified the sender in application.properties

Comment: Why and where do you use such properties?

Comment: @RomanC i followed this tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DLX8PMXaw0 that provided the assistance in using spring boot and smtp mail

Comment: What didn't you get from it?

Comment: @RomanC i followed the tutorial but getting the error above

Comment: What is printed in the console?

Comment: @RomanC updated the post with error log from console

Comment: In the code you are using `System.out.println(reservation1.getGuest().getEmail());` I don't see the output in the log.

Comment: @RomanC it prints out my email address i didnt add it in the log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message says that a local email address is missing. It means that sender's email address or in other words an address that consumer can use to reply on your message. This address is a property of `MimeMessage` that you use with `MimeMessageHelper`, and you can use it to set the address

[32.3 Using the JavaMail MimeMessageHelper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html#mail-javamail-mime)

> A class that comes in pretty handy when dealing with JavaMail messages is the `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper` class, which shields you from having to use the verbose JavaMail API. Using the `MimeMessageHelper` it is pretty easy to create a `MimeMessage`:

```
// of course you would use DI in any real-world cases
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("mail.host.com");

MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
helper.setFrom("your@email.address");
helper.setTo("test@host.com");
helper.setText("Thank you!");
sender.send(message);
```

This is the same code like on the doc page, but with addition of `setFrom()` which was missing only in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I added `helper.setFrom("local@email.com")` and it now work,

Thanks.