# Can't determine local email address; with spring boot when my application runs in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

When the application runs on my local machine I don't get this error but since I run my back end in aws with ECS I get the following error:

*"org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address"*

with status code 500.

```
 public void sendConformationEmail(User user, Locale locale, String appUrl){

    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    createVerificationToken(user, token);

    String recipientAddress = user.getEmail();
    String subject = "IO Employee Registration Confirmation";
    String confirmationUrl = appUrl + "/email/confirm?token=" + token;
    String message = messages.getMessage("message.regSuccLink", null, "You registered successfully. To confirm your registration, please click on the below link.", locale);

    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(recipientAddress);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setFrom(env.getProperty("spring.mail.username"));

    email.setText(message + "\r\n" + serverAddress + confirmationUrl);
    mailSender.send(email);
}
```

I use the Gmail SMTP server.

As you can see I use setFrom() so that can not be the issue. [can't determine local email address : Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452039/cant-determine-local-email-address-spring-boot)

Comment: Where is mailSender defined?

Comment: @delux247 on top of this emailservice, 
`import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;`
`private final JavaMailSender mailSender;`