# Using Java Mail API. javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address Exception

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using java mail API and it's working fine on a local machine but when I am deploying my web-app on a server, I'm getting an exception saying javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address.

this is my code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    try {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("fromEmailAdd@gmail.com", "fromEmailPass");
        }
    });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("sub");
        message.setText("msg");    
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("mail sent successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
```

Below given is the exception this code is throwing.

> javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this question:
[Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694468/failed-messages-javax-mail-messagingexception-cant-determine-local-email-addr)

The author seems to suggest that this exception is thrown when the **from** address is not set.

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@gmail.com"));
message.setFrom("from@gmail.com"); // <-- add 'from' email address
message.setSubject("sub");
message.setText("msg");    
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this issue prevail on the local machine then? It's working fine on local and not working after deploying it to the server :\

Comment: That is strange, if this is exactly the same code it should have failed on the local machine too. I know this will not resolve the issue of why it is not failing on the local machine, but have you tried message.setFrom(...) yet to so if it fixes the problem in the web-app?

Comment: I have managed to send an email from my local machine using your code (with my email settings) and like you by omitting message.setFrom(...) it does not throw the exception 
**javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address**

Comment: it's strange but it worked on server with your suggestion. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The message says that "local email address is missing", this means that sender's email address is missing. I think you could try to do something like this:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("mail.host.com")

MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
helper.setFrom("from@from.address");
helper.setTo("to@to.com");
helper.setText("testing text");
```

Comment: Isn't MimeMessageHelper  class from Spring framework? I'm not using Spring framework.

Comment: it is, if you don't you spring you could set it like this:    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
      mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
      mimeMessage.setFrom(sender);
      mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
      mimeMessage.setContent(html, TEXT_HTML);

Comment: Basically you are missing message.setFrom("your@mail.com");

Comment: Fab Sanchez also suggested this but then why is it working on local machine?