# "can't determine local email address" on 2 out of 7 supposedly identical servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, mime

I've consulted questions with the same title as this, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694468/failed-messages-javax-mail-messagingexception-cant-determine-local-email-addr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452039/cant-determine-local-email-address-spring-boot). I don't know Java. I'm not a software engineer. (I used to design chips and now teach it and that does have a lot in common with software engineering.)

I have a website which I am responsible for. This runs on 7 servers (currently) with haproxy as a load-balancer on an 8th server. All 7 servers are supposedly identical. In fact all are literally copies of each other. When some users try to register I get this error message:

> Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local
>   email address

followed by a ton of other stuff, which I'll put at the bottom. The thing is, it turns out, that this only happens on 2 of the 7 (supposedly identical) servers. Which is why it only happens to some users.

And, it seems like it only started happening a few days ago.

Please could you help me find how to diagnose this? To find where to look?

---

```
public class VelocityEmailService {

    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private final String encodingOptions = "utf-8";

    public void send(final String toEmailAddress, final String velocityEmailTemplate, final Map model, final String emailSubject) {
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo(toEmailAddress);
                message.setSubject(emailSubject);

                String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, velocityEmailTemplate, encodingOptions, model);

                message.setText(text, true);

            }
        };
        this.mailSender.send(preparator);      // line 32
    }

    public VelocityEngine getVelocityEngine() {
        return velocityEngine;
    }

    public void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
    }

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }
}
```

---

```
Could not load the requested page

Error: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address; message exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address

Error Message: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:355)
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:344)
com.victoreda.playground.services.VelocityEmailService.send(VelocityEmailService.java:32)
com.victoreda.playground.services.RegistrationService.sendEmail(RegistrationService.java:39)
com.victoreda.playground.services.RegistrationService.registerNewUser(RegistrationService.java:35)
com.victoreda.playground.facades.RegistrationFacade.registerNewUser(RegistrationFacade.java:23)
com.victoreda.playground.facades.RegistrationFacade$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b4d8bb.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
com.victoreda.playground.facades.RegistrationFacade$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54ace6aa.registerNewUser(<generated>)
com.victoreda.playground.controllers.RegistrationController.registerNewUser(RegistrationController.java:48)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4269.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1179)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? If yes I would look at _com.victoreda.playground.services.VelocityEmailService.send(VelocityEmailService.java:32)_ what e-mail address is used. Maybe the servers are not as identical as they should be and you are missing a config?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the source code. I'll have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @lugiorgi No clue there: I don't think. That line is identical. (git says all the source code is).

Comment: How do you set the _from_ part (the address where the mail recipients can reply to)? Is it loaded via an external property? If so is it configured correctly?

Comment: @lugiorgi There is no line that explicitly sets the _from_ part (like in the linked questions). But, it works on some servers, but not on others and (i) is identical on both and (ii) used to work on all of them (this problem only started in the last few days). I've added the source you highlighed to the question.

Comment: Do you recognize the _from_ email sent by the functioning servers? Maybe that can help you to find where the _from_ comes from.

Comment: @lugiorgi  I added `message.setFrom("getedaplayground@gmail.com");` at line 25 of the above code and it fixed it. Which is entirely logical given the error message. And it doesn't break a working server. But I wonder why some servers work and others don't and why it appears to have started breaking only within the last few days. Hmm... Anyway. Thank you very much for your help.